# Cost of dereferencing a variable on the stack, or dereferenced recently?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

With a modern compiler, is it as expensive to dereference a pointer a second time, when the data it points to was dereferenced recently?

```
int * ptr = new int(); 
... lots of stuff...
*ptr = 1; // may need to load the memory into the cpu
*ptr = 2; // accessed again, can I assume this will usually be loaded and cost nothing extra?
```

What if the pointer addresses a variable on the stack, can I assume reading/writing through a pointer to a stack variable costs the same as reading/writing directly to the variable?

```
int var;
int * ptr = &var;

*ptr = 0; // will this cost the same as if I just said var = 0; ?
```

And finally, does this extend to more complicated things, such as manipulating a base object on the stack through an interface?

```
Base baseObject;
Derived * derivedObject = &baseObject;
derivedObject->value = 42;    // will this have the same cost as if I just--
derivedObject->doSomething()  // --manipulated baseObject directly?
```

*Edit:* I'm asking this to gain a deeper understanding; this is less a problem to be solved than it is a request for insight.  Please don't worry about "premature-optimization" or other practical concerns, just give me all the rope you can :)

Comment: I guess more important is whether other functions were called inbetween which could change the value of the pointer. Then a reload is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question contains a number of ambiguities.

A simple rule of thumb is that dereferencing something will always have the same cost, except when it doesn't.

There are a number of factors in the cost of a dereference - is the destination in cache, is it paged and the code generated by the compiler.

For the code snippet

```
Obj* p = new Obj;
// <elided> //
p->something = 1;
```

looking at this source code we can't tell whether the executable will have `p`s value loaded, whether *p is in cache or whether *p has even been accessed.

```
Obj* p = new Obj;
p->something = 1;
```

We still can't be sure whether *p is paged/cached, but most modern compilers/optimizers will not emit code that retrieves `p` and stores it and then fetches it again.

In practice on modern hardware, you really shouldn't be concerned with it, and if you are, start by looking at the assembly.

I'll use two ends of the spectrum:

```
struct Obj { int something; int other; };

Obj* f() {
  Obj* p = new Obj;
  p->something = 1;
  p->other = 2;
  return p;
}

extern void fn2(Obj**);

Obj* h() {
  Obj* p = new Obj;
  fn2(&p);
  p->something = 1;
  fn2(&p);
  p->other = 2;
  return p;
}
```

This [produces](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall',sourcez:AQ4ZwFwJwVwYwsA8gIwFbAN7AJYDtEwB7AWwFMIALfAcwG5cDgiqyoGBfOgKG9GXQAqYADMAFAEosffgLTCADsAC8wPGQDucnrOAKAtAD5i5KrRXAAjDtkHDLSmwsAmG/ygUYUPHrfAOvPxkAB4QbD4AbkQ4ACaieM5iqPKCEjwyIMnClJLSull6FupayX4gIgliAGQKaRmgdiYU1Hg0Ftb15ZU1dbp2Dk6qrp3AHhBePgp%2BHEAAAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
f():
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $8, %edi
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        movl    $1, (%rax)
        movl    $2, 4(%rax)
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

and

```
h():
        subq    $24, %rsp
        movl    $8, %edi
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
        movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
        call    fn2(Obj**)
        movq    8(%rsp), %rax
        leaq    8(%rsp), %rdi
        movl    $1, (%rax)
        call    fn2(Obj**)
        movq    8(%rsp), %rax
        movl    $2, 4(%rax)
        addq    $24, %rsp
        ret
```

Here the compiler has to preserve and restore the pointer to dereference it after the call, but that's a bit unfair because the pointer could be modified by the called function.

```
Obj* h() {
  Obj* p = new Obj;
  fn2(nullptr);
  p->something = 1;
  fn2(nullptr);
  p->other = 2;
  return p;
}
```

produces

```
h():
        pushq   %rbx
        movl    $8, %edi
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        xorl    %edi, %edi
        movq    %rax, %rbx
        call    fn2(Obj**)
        xorl    %edi, %edi
        movl    $1, (%rbx)
        call    fn2(Obj**)
        movq    %rbx, %rax
        movl    $2, 4(%rbx)
        popq    %rbx
        ret
```

we're still seeing some register shenanigans, but it's hardly expensive.

As for your questions about pointers to the stack, a good optimizer will be able to eliminate those, but again you have to consult the assembly generated by your chosen compiler for your particular platform.

```
struct Obj { int something; int other; };

void fn(Obj*);

void f()
{
  Obj o;
  Obj* p = &o;
  p->something = 1;
  p->other = 1;
  fn(p);
}
```

[produces](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11+-Wall',source:'++++struct+Obj+%7B+int+something%3B+int+other%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0A++++void+fn(Obj*)%3B%0A%0A++++void+f()%0A++++%7B%0A++++++Obj+o%3B%0A++++++Obj*+p+%3D+%26o%3B%0A++++++p-%3Esomething+%3D+1%3B%0A++++++p-%3Eother+%3D+1%3B%0A++++++fn(p)%3B%0A++++%7D')),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3) the following where `p` has basically been eliminated.

```
f():
        subq    $24, %rsp
        movq    %rsp, %rdi
        movl    $1, (%rsp)
        movl    $1, 4(%rsp)
        call    fn(Obj*)
        addq    $24, %rsp
        ret
```

Of course, if we passed `&p` to something, the compiler wouldn't be able to elide it entirely, but it still might be smart enough to avoid using it when it didn't absolutely have to.

Answer (score 1):

Trust the compiler.

Be pretty sure the compiler will generate code to do the less amount of work as possible, taking into account peculiarities of the CPU architecture, and anything the compiler can take into account.

Answer (score 1):

> With a modern compiler, is it as expensive to dereference a pointer a
>   second time, when the data it points to was dereferenced recently?

With full optimization, the compiler might be able to rearrange the code (depending on the code), or perhaps stash the pointer into a register, or perhaps stash the value in a register ... so maybe.

One might look at the generated assy code to confirm.

I considered this premature optimization.

Also, if you are thinking of cache, then possibly (but not guaranteed), when close together in time and when both mem addresses are in the same cache block, the two dereferences through the pointer will each access the cache mem without a cache miss.

Any writes will be placed in cache, and delivered to memory when the cache hw gets around to it or a cache miss causes the flush to memory.

---

> What if the pointer addresses a variable on the stack, can I assume
>   reading/writing through a pointer to a stack variable costs the same
>   as reading/writing directly to the variable?

I doubt that you could or should assume anything.  You might inspect the generated assy to see what your compiler did with this code on this target architecture and with this compiler version and build option choices, etc.  Hundreds if not thousands of variables which might affect the code gen.

Note that data cache works for stack accesses, also.

Again, I consider this premature optimization.

---

> And finally, does this extend to more complicated things, such as
>   manipulating a base object on the stack through an interface?

In general, the compiler does a good job.  So, in that sense, possibly.  Not guaranteed.

I think using move semantics (a C++ feature) is valuable, but that is maybe not relate-able to your questions here.

Hardware cache is probably more important than any amount of cycle counts you may wish to manually count (or simulate).  I was impressed how much data cache (for automatic variables and dynamic variables) improved the performance on an embedded system. But the code cache was impressive too.  I would not want to do with out either of them.

---

By premature optimization I mean that

a) humans are notoriously unable to understand (or 'guess') where the hot spots are in their programs, i.e. the 20% of the code consume 80% of cycles idea. That is why there are tools to help pin-point them.

b) I have always heard that the better algorithms outperform other choices, and I would say that is usually true.  The better algorithms are what you should be learning.  From your SO rep, you probably know more than I do.

However, I feel readability is the more appropriate criteria for evaluation.  The feedback from former colleagues I like to hear is, "...we still use your code."  because that statement suggests that it works, has not given them too much trouble, is fast enough, and (most important) readable.

c) counting cycles in any code can only be attempted with simulation. I've done it for an embedded military processor.

To simulate cache actions, you actually have to have usable code to evaluate, have to understand the interactions between processor and cache, and have to know cache block sizes of both data and instruction cache.

To choose the faster (as a criteria)  is ... well if the first version meets the requirements, your customer (boss, team lead, etc.) will probably be unwilling to wait for / pay for faster code.

I've been on one big project to fix 'a system' that was deemed too slow (predecessor choices, not mine) ... management chose the safe to understand and cost estimate path: re-design the processor card with about 10x more processing cycles and 32x more ram.  The software team refactored the code, and added the newest features as best we could.  From overloaded, the new 'system' was running at 1/3 duty cycle.  Big improvement that was visible in every command response time.

Comment: In reread ... maybe this answer is not enough C++, and too much system issues.

Answer (score 0):

For Example 1 and 2, it depends on the context. Just doing stores if you are not using them, compiler will just ignore those. For the last example, it is a compilation error, you cannot point to `Base` object from `Derived*`

Check for yourself:

https://godbolt.org/g/pMiOfj

If Base extends, derived case (from example in comment):
Again the answer depends on how much information compiler knows. If it can see that it is just the object in stack, it will optimize and both of them 
will be equivalent. https://godbolt.org/g/jIKQJv

Note: You don't have to worry about such details, Compiler knows better to optimize. Use the notion that is more readable. This is premature optimization.

Comment: 1 and 2 are just short examples, they would be used in practice.  3 is legal, here's how they they might be implemented https://godbolt.org/g/djgW2e

Comment: Usually `Base` is the base class and `Derived` extends from base.